# Constantly get "?" as score and FMP error on pagespeed insight

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I use pagespeed insight to audit thise site:

http://www.omniwaresoft.com.tw/docker/

But I can't get result like usual, instead it shows "?" and "error (NO_FMP)" for First CPU Idle, FMP and dom ready.

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWSeC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with the simulated throttling on Page Speed Insights.

I cannot pinpoint the problem but I would guess it is related to some strange behaviour on your site where the site starts loading in and then there is a quick flash and the content then animates in.

Also as you have a lot of assets set to https in source but don't have an SSL certificate the 307 redirects could cause an error somewhere.

Certain Chinese character combinations have been known to cause issues with Lighthouse (the engine behind Page Speed Insights) under throttling although the exact cause I am not sure of.

### Workaround

Obviously once the site has SSL etc. the problem could go away.

In the mean time if you go to Developer Tools -> Audits you have the option to deselect 'Simulated Throttling'. If you do that then it does work, although the score is always about 3-5 points lower than simulated throttling so bear that in mind.

**newer chrome versions** -> the option to deselect the 'Simulated Throttling' is now only visible if you click the settings icon (gear / cog) in the top right of the audits page, took me a few seconds to work out where they had hidden it. Also make sure that 'Clear Storage' is checked so that you get a score as if it was a new visitor to the site.

Comment: I turned Simulated Throttling and it works. Now the score shows.

Comment: I'll put SSL upgrade in schedule as well !
BTW, How do I tell if my assets are set to htts? Didn't recall any change for that..

Comment: Add, mobile score remains "?" while desktop shows number.

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed Lighthouse reports an error on the "too many redirects" as well as an error for "defer off -screen content".

It works as expected if the page is scrolled to the end before the audit is complete. And as https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702894/graham-ritchie noted, it only happens if a slow network is simulated.

There seems to be more than one plugin trying to cache content. Try turning one or both of those off.

Some of the lazy loaded image tags have a src value with a HTTPS protocol on the CDN and a lazy loaded image (data-src) on the server with a HTTP protocol. Try turning lazy loaded images off and if that fixes it, try making sure both src and data-src use the same protocol.

It also seems like something is causing assets that are 404 errors to return the URL of the page.

One last thing I noticed: The Autoptimize plugin does not seem to be resulting in optimized performance—the time to first byte is sometimes over 4 seconds. Maybe try turning it and any other plugins caching off, empty the caches they've created and look at PageSpeed.

In general, turn plugins off and see if the PageSpeed problem is fixed and even if performance is better with them off.

Comment: That's weird.. I thought Autoptimize should do the trick makes my site quicker.
And I can't figure out why "too many redirects", the most likely thing I did was redirect URL/mongodb to URL/mongodb/ with .htaccess file.
Thanks for your help!